# PHP how to create table using multidimensional array

Tags: php

This is the layout I want
[image]

Here is my code, but something isn't right?

```
<?php
//
$details = array
  (

  array("Peter", "Texas"),
  array("Mike", "California"),


  array (

    array("Jack","Utah"),
    array("Roger", "New York"), 
    array("Rocky", "Utah")
  )

  );

  print_r ($details);

?>
```

Comment: `print_r()` is more of a debugging method to show the data, you will need to layout the table yourself using loops etc.

Comment: As said, print_r will not get you there. You need HTML, specifically the table element of html. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp This may be a good way to start your journey

Comment: _“Here is my code, but something isn't right?”_ - pretending that using nothing but `print_r` was an _actual_ attempt to try and solve the problem here, is not right to begin with. And the arrangement / structure of your shown data doesn’t appear to make much sense, related to the desired output, either. Why are the first two “records” on the main array level next to each other, but then the next three are grouped in an additional array level? Why do Jack and Roger create a line in the table, but Rocky just disappears silently? And where’s the College A / B association supposed to come from?

Answer (score 0):

```
$table = array(
    'College A' => array(
        array(
            'Name' => 'Peter',
            'State' => 'Texas'
        ),
        array(
            'Name' => 'Mile',
            'State' => 'California'
        ),
    ),
    'College B' => array(
        array(
            'Name' => 'Jack',
            'State' => 'Utah'
        ),
        array(
            'Name' => 'Roger',
            'State' => 'New York'
        ),
    ),
);

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td></td><td>Name</td><td>State</td></tr>';
foreach ($table as $key => $value ){
    //... echo '<tr><td>...
}
echo '</table>'
```